# Reconnect to ROSCORE

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are developing a robot that has some processing done off-board, for that we rely on a WiFi connection and a dynamic DNS for the robot's laptop.
On the desktop side I've configured it to connect to the laptop but there are problems when the laptop disconnect and reconnect to the WiFi, despite the dynamic DNS. I've created a ping thread similar to "rostopic ping", that I can use to detect possible disconnections, but I haven't found a way to reconnect to roscore.

Any help on how could I reconnect to roscore?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10730/reconnect-to-roscore/) by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 408 on 2011-07-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless you are actively creating new publishers/subscribers, there is no need to 'reconnect' to a roscore.  The roscore acts as a DNS server -- it just stores lookup information.   There is no connection that is maintained between your node and the roscore.

It would be helpful if you described why you believe you need to reconnect.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2011-08-31**:
In my case I have ROSCORE running on-board the robot, and some process run off-board. The robot has a wifi connection that sometimes drops killing all connections between off-board process and the robot.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-28**:
That use case isn't well supported -- in general, you want something that restarts the entire Python process if possible.  There is an experimental package called ronin that restarts a remote publisher, but it's far from stable: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ronin

**Comment by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) on 2011-08-27**:
In my situation,  I am running a ros client on a windows machine without ssh access. so roslaunch cannot start the node remotely. Instead I start the node once and hope the node to re-announce itself everytime I restart the whole "launch" when the "DNS" server is fresh.